# Unresolved External Symbols when using CUDA Driver API VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cuda

I've been trying to use the CUDA driver API to load a .ptx file and a function from it with this code:

```
CUdevice device;
cuDeviceGet(&device,0);
CUcontext ctx;
cuCtxCreate(&ctx,0,device);
CUmodule mod;
cuModuleLoad(&mod,"kernel.ptx");
CUfunction func;
cuModuleGetFunction(&func,mod,"kernel");
CUdeviceptr ints;
cuMemAlloc(&ints,(sizeof(int)*30));
```

However at compile time I get these errors:

```
    1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cuDeviceGet@8 referenced in function _main
    1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cuCtxCreate_v2@12 referenced in function _main
    1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cuModuleLoad@8 referenced in function _main
    1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cuModuleGetFunction@12 referenced in function _main
    1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cuMemAlloc_v2@8 referenced in function _main
    1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cuMemcpyHtoD_v2@12 referenced in function _main
    1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cuMemcpyDtoH_v2@12 referenced in function _main
    1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cuLaunchKernel@44 referenced in function _main
```

I created a new CUDA 5.5 project in VS2012 and typed this directly into the generated .cu file however at compile time I got these errors. If I do a test that doesn't use the driver api I don't get any errors!

Comment: Please don't use pastebin. Edit the *relevant* information in the question itself.

Comment: Check out this link: [Windows CUDA 5 and Visual Studio 2012](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CUDA-50-and-Visual-Studio-20e71aa1).  The key thing is to set up Visual Studio correctly.

Comment: The cuda installer (the newest one at least) does this automatically at install. And the code given at that link will compile with no problem! I'm thinking problem with the linker but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Are you linking against cuda.lib?

Comment: *facepalm* That fixed it. It was only linked to cudart.lib.

Comment: @LucasS: Perhaps you could add this as an answer to the question (it is allowed to answer your own question). That way the question gets off the unanswered queue and leaves a clean solution for the next person with this problem.

Comment: @kronos if you post this as an answer (link against libcuda) I would upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those errors occur when you are not linking against `cuda.lib`.

Answer (score 1):

For those who does not know how to add `cuda.lib` into linking process like me (using VS2017):

1. Right click on the project, goto `Properties` at the bottom of the menu
2. Goto `Linker-->Input`
3. In `Additional Dependencies`, make sure that `cuda.lib` is there. In my case, this solved the 2019 link error.
4. Besides, if you click on the `edit` item in the drop menu, there is a `Macros` button that you can click and view all pre-defined Macros in your VS project.